# emacs ido-buffer : group buffers by directories

Tags: emacs, ido

Is it possible to view the open `buffers` grouped by `directories` in `emacs ido-buffer mode`, in some sort of tree representation?

Comment: Here, I mean `ibuffer` by `ido-buffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"emacs ido-buffer mode" ??

Did you mean `ibuffer`? If so...

It's not *grouping*<sup>1</sup>, but sorting by filename is a fairly useful approximation, and is available by default.

<kbd>s</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>

Unfortunately (to my mind) dired buffers aren't included. You might fix that by defining a variant of the sorter which includes them, and then remapping the binding:

```el
(eval-after-load 'ibuffer
  '(progn
     (define-ibuffer-sorter filename/directory/process
       "Sort the buffers by their file name/process name."
       (:description "file name")
       (string-lessp
        (or (buffer-file-name (car a))
            (let ((dir (buffer-local-value 'dired-directory (car a))))
              (if (consp dir) (car dir) dir))
            (let ((pr-a (get-buffer-process (car a))))
              (and (processp pr-a) (process-name pr-a))))
        (or (buffer-file-name (car b))
            (let ((dir (buffer-local-value 'dired-directory (car b))))
              (if (consp dir) (car dir) dir))
            (let ((pr-b (get-buffer-process (car b))))
              (and (processp pr-b) (process-name pr-b))))))

     (define-key ibuffer-mode-map
       [remap ibuffer-do-sort-by-filename/process]
       'ibuffer-do-sort-by-filename/directory/process)))
```

<sup>1</sup> A function to dynamically group by directory would be nifty.